# Some programas shows ghost windows

Tags: window-management, user-interface, gtk

It seems to happen on software written on java. For example DBeaver or MySQL Workbench when you run some feature, the emergent window shows with a ghost window background like next image:

[image]

I think is an issue related with GTK libraries. It not avoid to use the apps but sometimes can be annoying.

Have someone experimented something similar? How did you fixed it?

Comment: Yes, I have experienced this glitch while working with DisplayCAL application (see pic). I thought it was this particular application's issue. [![ghost window on DisplayCAL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cUzW.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cUzW.jpg)

Comment: Hey I'm pretty sure this is a known bug. If you search on the elementary gala GitHub page you'll see the bug report. However I don't think it's fixed yet.